# How to maintain a linear history in git

Tags: git

For different reasons, I am required to maintain a linear `master` branch. That is, commits in that branch cannot have more than one parent.

There are multiple people on our team and we would like to make `feature` branches to work together on. Usually we rebase our own personal commits on this `feature` branch, then merge it into our `devel` branch when the feature is ready. We also depends on a `foreign` project (which uses different branches, but we will assume here that it is all in a single `foreign` branch which has its own separate origin) that we regularly merge into our `devel` branch.

However, all this work has to be eventually forwarded to the `master` branch in linear form. We could squash all those changes into a single commit in `master` (using `git reset --soft devel`) then merge `master` back into `devel`. However, we would like to preserve our commits as much as possible:

- Every commit message (including merge message) should be preserved
- Topological order between commits has to be preserved
- Commits that merge from the `foreign` branch have to be squashed into a single 'merge' commit (without the parent information unfortunately)
- Branch `master`, `devel`, `feature`, `foreign` have to be kept perfect-forward compatible (as this is a shared repository)

My initial idea was to:

1. create a `staging` branch from `devel`
2. rebase `staging` ontop of `master`
3. merge back the new `staging` into `devel`.

But this didn't work-out because:

- the `foreign` branch, was rebased from it's origin and not squashed
- I had to handle every conflicts from `devel` again, while they were already handled during our many merging process in `devel` itself

So I am planning to do the following:

Let's call `div` the latest commit of `devel` not in `master` (latest divergence point). If `master` has new commits that are not merged into `devel`, abort. That is, if there are new commit in `master` after `div`, they have to be merged by hand, into `devel`, prior to this.

For each commit from `div` to `devel` (in topological order), perform a `git reset --soft` and commit the changes into `master` (with the same commit message). This means that:

- commits that are not after `div` but are before `devel` are squashed: those were either merge from `foreign` (in which case we are happy) or merge from `master` (in which case the actual commit are already in master)
- commits that are in between get properly pushed into `master` one after another, except for parallel branch of `devel` which will look like commit undoing the other side at each time (which is ugly, but probably unavoidable)

And finally, I merge `master` back into `devel` and this merge commit becomes the `div` for next time.

As I would like to minimize the number of 'undo'/'redo' I would add the following restriction to the chosen topological order: a commit in `devel` with only one parent would have the equivalent commit as a parent in `master`.

All in all, this seems overly complicated. Is there a built-in way to have a linear branch follow a non-linear branch? Else, would my strategy work or am I missing really important details?

Comment: Considering the risky nature of squash-commits and rebasing, it doesn't sound like using feature branches is the solution for your team.  You may want to commit directly to master instead (less ideal than feature branches, sure, but achieves the linear history that you desire with less risk of losing commits).

Comment: i don't think you can maintain master and develop branches and accomplish this goal.  Your best bet seems to be to drop develop, branch features off of master, then rebase the feature branch just prior to merging into master.  If you want to "assemble" feature branches prior to merging into master, you can use a throw-away integration branch and try to leverage rerere to avoid having to redo merge conflicts when merging into master

Comment: What about the `foreign` branch? I cannot rebase it (it is not under my control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [@jamey's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39856434/how-to-maintain-a-linear-history-in-git#comment67001137_39856434), it would probably be best to drop the `develop` branch, split feature branches off of `master`, and rebase prior to merging into `master`. When you are done with a feature branch, you can do:

```
git rebase master myfeature
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only myfeature
```

When you need to merge in changes from the `foreign` branch, do:

```
git merge --squash foreign
git commit
```

From the man page for `git merge`:

> `--squash`
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit, move the `HEAD`, or record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` (to cause the next `git commit` command to create a merge commit). This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in the case of an octopus).